# Randomly generate text, based on a Linkedhashmap of key=String and Value=following Char

Tags: java, string, random, character, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap`called `generateMap`which contains a string as a key and all possible variations of the following character of this string stored as value(s).
Now I'd like to print a random text. (The storage of the String is not the issue)

```
Example:
String = "Lorem ipsum Loram ipar"

Key----------Value
After Lor -> e,a
After ore -> m
After rem -> " "
After em  -> i
After m i -> p,p
After  ip -> s,a
```

The random text should be generated with randomly chosen next character, then the next "window" is chosen, and so on. I have no idea how to generate a new text, maybe you can give me a hint? 
This is what I got so far:

```
for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> e : generateMap.entrySet()) {
            //store the values into an ArrayList        
            ArrayList<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(e.getValue());
            // randomly choose on of the values
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * (valuesList.size()));
            String randomWort = valuesList.get(random);
            String print = e.getKey() + randomWort;
}
System.out.println(print);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is ok. In convenient way, to use Guava class [LinkedHashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html).

A small improvement: you do not need create an ArrayList in the loop, `e.getValue()` is ArrayList already.

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu – I heard of Guava, but I'm not allowed to use this library (yet).

Comment: Thanks for your improvement.
But it prints sth like this, not a single text, but I need to have a text which doesnt repeat words (descripted above): `HausA 
ausA H
usA Ha
sA Hau
A Haus
 HausB
HausB`

Comment: Regarding to no-repeat, Set came into my mind. You can try HashSet to do it.